# Class of function which $\int_0^{\infty} x^{a-1} e^{-f(x)} dx$ is defined

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

I am looking for a class of functions, which the following integral can be defined, and has a closed form value.
$$
\int_0^{\infty} x^{a-1} e^{-f(x)} dx
$$
where $a$ is an integer.

Quadratic functions have this property. But, do the higher powers have closed form?

Comment: You can have $f(x)=x^k$ and have a closed form with the [Incomplete gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html) or you can do $f(x)=-\ln(g(x))$ and have a [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform). Are there any restrictions on $f(x)$?

Comment: Thanks. No there is no condition on f, maybe continuity.

Comment: Restricting that $f$ should have a “closed form” is essentially an intractable problem